# Possible to use absolute imports from within and relative to subpackage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-import

Given the following package structure:

```
repo1
└── subpackage
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── module1.py
    └── module2.py
```

This `subpackage` uses absolute import paths like:

```
# module1.py
from subpackage.module2 import my_function
```

Now the repository `repo1` is included in another repository `repo2` via Git subtree:

```
repo2
├── main.py
└── repo1
    └── subpackage
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── module1.py
        └── module2.py
```

Imports from `repo2` work as expected i.e. `from repo1.subpackage.module2 import my_function`.

But now the absolute imports within `repo1` are no longer valid.

**Are we forced to use relative imports for `repo1`?**

Comment: `repo1` is not a package; it's just a directory. I'm guessing you are importing `module1` from a script located in `repo1`, which means `repot1` is included in the Python path for that script.

Comment: Yes, but would it being a package (by adding an additional `__init__.py`) change anything with respect to the issue?

Comment: Yes: assuming `main.py` is the script that imports `module1`, its Python path includes the directory it is located in. It can't find `subpackage` in its path because its buried in a non-package directory `repo1`.

Comment: However, you would then have to change the absolute import to `from repo1.subpackage.module2 import my_function`. One purpose of relative imports is to make imports like this agnostic to the location of its parent package.

Comment: Or, you would somehow have to explicitly add `repo1` to the Python path.

Comment: "However, you would then have to change the absolute import" that is the reason for my question. `repo1` is added via Git subtree. We can't change the imports. The python path will be set to `repo2`. That is exactly the question I'm asking.

Comment: Repository `repo1` has to stay valid as independent repository and should use absolute imports. I'm asking if this is even possible.

Comment: Your script should not be forced to accommodate your repository layout. Run  your script from a proper installation, which acts as the middle man between your working directories and a proper package hierarchy.

Comment: @chepner I'm not sure I understand what you are suggesting. What are you referring to with "script", "proper installation", "working directories" and "proper package hierarchy"?
The problem that we try to solve is code reuse in multiple repositories (e.g. utils, database methods, ...). Git subtree did seem like the best solution but that brings us to the above described problem.